# Serialization of 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' is not allowed (php unit)

Tags: mongodb, phpunit

I switched from [mongodb](http://php.net/manual/de/class.mongoclient.php) to [MongoDB\Driver\Manager](http://php.net/manual/de/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php).
I re-wrote my persistence class and the persistenceTest class. Everything worked fine. Than i restarted my pc and the test failed with the error message:

```
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Serialization of 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' is not allowed
```

I simplified the problem to a very basic class and classTest.

The Class:

```
class Abc
{
    protected $x;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $driverOptions = [ 'typeMap' => [ 'root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array', 'array' => 'array' ] ];
        $manager = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://user7:user777@localhost", [], $driverOptions);
        $this->x = new MongoDB\Database($manager, 'testDB', $driverOptions);
        $d = $this->x->{'testCollection'}->find();
        foreach ($d as $e) var_dump($e);
    }
}
$y = new Abc();
```

The TestClass:

```
class AbcTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test123(){}
}
```

I working on windows with php 5.6.30 PHPUnit 5.7.21 and "mongodb/mongodb": "1.1.2".

Any Ideas why it worked in the first place and now i got this error message?
AND the class itself works, called via apache, it delivers the content of the testCollection without errors or warnings.

Comment: After 2 days testing, i think the problem is that a object member var could not hold the Manager class if there are too many levels of object->var = object->var = ... = new MongoDB\Client(). The solution for me is put it in a static member var self::$persistens = new Manager\Client() .....

Comment: Could you post your solution to this question? I'm getting the same error message and I am intrigued by what you wrote, would like to figure out where it goes.